# Remove a user from all Active Directory Groups with C#

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I have a WCF service written in C# that performs actions on user and group objects in Active Directory. For one of the operations available on this service I need to remove all groups from a specific user.

I was able to do this using this code, but it takes longer than 30 seconds and I'd like to avoid expanding the timeout.

```
foreach (GroupPrincipal group in user.GetGroups(this._context))
{
   // We've set the primary group to Domain Users so we want to skip this group now.
   if (group.Name.ToUpper().Equals(DOMAIN_USERS.ToUpper()))
   {
      continue;
   }

   // Remove the user and save the group.
   group.Members.Remove(user);
   group.Save();
   group.Dispose();
}
```

I also tried this code but I'm getting an error from AD that says "Server unwilling to perform request."

```
var userEntry = (DirectoryEntry)user.GetUnderlyingObject();
userEntry.Properties["memberOf"].Clear();
userEntry.CommitChanges();
userEntry.Dispose();
```

What can I do to make the first code block more efficient? Is there another way to remove a user from all groups that I have not considered?

Comment: I don't see anyway to make it "faster" its only going to be as fast as it takes to retrieve the information from the domain server.

Comment: Is there any way to do a "bulk save" so I don't have to go to the DC for every group?

Comment: I suppose thats possible but you would still have to access the server to get the information which is where the real performance cost is.  You might be able to get better performance out of Powershell script.  This eliminates the overhead of the .NET framework, which can still be ran from the service, if you wanted.

Comment: I tried a PowerShell script and the still wasn't able to get under 30 seconds. I ended up just switching the wcf call to async.

Comment: any final solution about it ?